# Extend box for today and yesterday

Tags: pine-script

Good morning,

How would I extend the boxes within the below script for only today and yesterday?

I can get the boxes to appear and extend all. But would like to have the option to just extend today and yesterdays. This could be as separate options.

Boxes
[image]

Extend all (looks to messy and doesn't achieve)
[image]

Below I have used the drawing tool to show what I would like to display
[image]
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © Frien_dd

```
//@version=4
study("Asia IB Testing - Delete Me", overlay = true)

AsiaInputColor = input(color.purple, title="Asia", group = "Session Boxes - Settings", inline = "Input 1") 


NoBoxIBOutline = input(true, title="Turn IB Box Outline On/Off", group="Session Boxes - Settings")
NoBoxIBBGColor = input(true, title="Turn IB Box Background Colour On/Off", group="Session Boxes - Settings")
BGIBGradiant = input(85,title="Box IB Background color gradiant", group="Session Boxes - Settings")

//#######################################################################################
////////How do I incorperate this, so that the user can select to extend only today IBs/box and yesterdays
//#######################################################################################
isToday = dayofmonth(time) == dayofmonth(timenow)
ExtendOnlyToday = isToday ? extend.right : na


ExtendIBBox = input(false, title="Extend previous and todays Intial Balance Boxes")

ExtendOption = ExtendIBBox ? extend.right : extend.none

Switch = input(true, title="Dotted/Solid Box Outline", group="Session Boxes - Settings")

SolidDotted = Switch ? line.style_solid : line.style_dotted
AsiaBoxIBOutline = NoBoxIBOutline ? AsiaInputColor : na
AsiaBoxIBBGColor = NoBoxIBBGColor ? color.new(AsiaInputColor, BGIBGradiant) : na




//// Asia Initial Balance
AsiaIBOnOff = input(true, title = "", group = 'Session Boxes', inline = "2")

AsiaIBTimeRangeInput = input("0130-0230", "Asia IB Session", input.session, group = 'Session Boxes', inline = "2")
AsiaIBDateRange = ":1234567"
AsiaIBTimeRange = AsiaIBTimeRangeInput+AsiaIBDateRange
AsiaIBinRange = time(timeframe.period, AsiaIBTimeRange)


// AsiaIBTimeRange = input("0130-0230:1234567", type=input.session, title='Asia IB Session', group = 'Session Boxes') 
// AsiaIBinRange = (time(timeframe.period, AsiaIBTimeRange))

// First and Last bar in Range
AsiaIBStart = AsiaIBinRange and not AsiaIBinRange[1]
AsiaIBEnd = not AsiaIBinRange and AsiaIBinRange[1]

// Bar Index of Start and End
AsiaIBStartIndex = 0, AsiaIBEndIndex = 0
AsiaIBStartIndex := AsiaIBStart? bar_index : AsiaIBStartIndex[1]
AsiaIBEndIndex := AsiaIBEnd? bar_index : AsiaIBEndIndex[1]

// Calculate Highs and Lows
AsiaIBHigh = 0.0, AsiaIBLow = 0.0
AsiaIBHigh := high >= AsiaIBHigh[1]? high : AsiaIBHigh[1]
AsiaIBLow := low <=AsiaIBLow[1]? low : AsiaIBLow[1]

// Reset at start of range
AsiaIBHigh := AsiaIBStart? high : AsiaIBHigh
AsiaIBLow := AsiaIBStart? low : AsiaIBLow

// Get open and close for range
AsiaIBOpen = 0.0, AsiaIBClose = 0.0
AsiaIBOpen := AsiaIBStart? open : AsiaIBOpen[1]
AsiaIBClose := AsiaIBEnd? close : AsiaIBClose[1]


// Draw previous boxes
if AsiaIBEnd and AsiaIBOnOff
    AsiaIBBox = box.new(AsiaIBStartIndex, AsiaIBHigh, AsiaIBEndIndex, AsiaIBLow, AsiaBoxIBOutline, 1, SolidDotted, ExtendOption,bgcolor=AsiaBoxIBBGColor)

// Draw current box if currently in range
box AsiaIBBox = na
if AsiaIBinRange and barstate.islast and AsiaIBOnOff
    AsiaIBBox := box.new(AsiaIBStartIndex, AsiaIBHigh, bar_index, AsiaIBLow, AsiaBoxIBOutline, 1, SolidDotted, ExtendOption,bgcolor=AsiaBoxIBBGColor)
    box.delete(AsiaIBBox[1])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer below:

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// Â© Frien_dd

//@version=4
study("Asia IB Testing - Delete Me", overlay = true)

AsiaInputColor = input(color.purple, title="Asia", group = "Session Boxes - Settings", inline = "Input 1") 


NoBoxIBOutline = input(true, title="Turn IB Box Outline On/Off", group="Session Boxes - Settings")
NoBoxIBBGColor = input(true, title="Turn IB Box Background Colour On/Off", group="Session Boxes - Settings")
BGIBGradiant = input(85,title="Box IB Background color gradiant", group="Session Boxes - Settings")

isToday = dayofmonth(time) == dayofmonth(timenow)

ExtendIBTodayBox = input(false, title="Extend todays Intial Balance Boxes")
ExtendIBYesterdayBox = input(false, title="Extend previous days Intial Balance Boxes")

Switch = input(true, title="Dotted/Solid Box Outline", group="Session Boxes - Settings")

SolidDotted = Switch ? line.style_solid : line.style_dotted
AsiaBoxIBOutline = NoBoxIBOutline ? AsiaInputColor : na
AsiaBoxIBBGColor = NoBoxIBBGColor ? color.new(AsiaInputColor, BGIBGradiant) : na

//// Asia Initial Balance
AsiaIBOnOff = input(true, title = "", group = 'Session Boxes', inline = "2")

AsiaIBTimeRangeInput = input("0130-0230", "Asia IB Session", input.session, group = 'Session Boxes', inline = "2")
AsiaIBDateRange = ":1234567"
AsiaIBTimeRange = AsiaIBTimeRangeInput+AsiaIBDateRange
AsiaIBinRange = time(timeframe.period, AsiaIBTimeRange)

// First and Last bar in Range
AsiaIBStart = AsiaIBinRange and not AsiaIBinRange[1]
AsiaIBEnd = not AsiaIBinRange and AsiaIBinRange[1]

// Bar Index of Start and End
AsiaIBStartIndex = 0, AsiaIBEndIndex = 0
AsiaIBStartIndex := AsiaIBStart? bar_index : AsiaIBStartIndex[1]
AsiaIBEndIndex := AsiaIBEnd? bar_index : AsiaIBEndIndex[1]

// Calculate Highs and Lows
AsiaIBHigh = 0.0, AsiaIBLow = 0.0
AsiaIBHigh := high >= AsiaIBHigh[1]? high : AsiaIBHigh[1]
AsiaIBLow := low <=AsiaIBLow[1]? low : AsiaIBLow[1]

// Reset at start of range
AsiaIBHigh := AsiaIBStart? high : AsiaIBHigh
AsiaIBLow := AsiaIBStart? low : AsiaIBLow

// Get open and close for range
AsiaIBOpen = 0.0, AsiaIBClose = 0.0
AsiaIBOpen := AsiaIBStart? open : AsiaIBOpen[1]
AsiaIBClose := AsiaIBEnd? close : AsiaIBClose[1]

// Draw previous boxes
if AsiaIBEnd and AsiaIBOnOff
    AsiaIBBox = box.new(AsiaIBStartIndex, AsiaIBHigh, AsiaIBEndIndex, AsiaIBLow, AsiaBoxIBOutline, 1, SolidDotted, extend.none,bgcolor=AsiaBoxIBBGColor)


// Draw previous boxes
if AsiaIBEnd and AsiaIBOnOff and isToday and ExtendIBTodayBox
    AsiaIBBox = box.new(AsiaIBStartIndex, AsiaIBHigh, AsiaIBEndIndex, AsiaIBLow, AsiaBoxIBOutline, 1, SolidDotted, extend.right,bgcolor=AsiaBoxIBBGColor)

// Draw Previous IB Box
isYesterday = dayofmonth(time[1]) == dayofmonth(timenow[1])
PrevAsiaIBHigh = valuewhen(bar_index==AsiaIBEndIndex,AsiaIBHigh,1)
PrevAsiaIBLow = valuewhen(bar_index==AsiaIBEndIndex,AsiaIBLow,1)
if AsiaIBEnd and AsiaIBOnOff and isYesterday and ExtendIBYesterdayBox
    AsiaIBBox = box.new(AsiaIBStartIndex[1], PrevAsiaIBHigh, AsiaIBEndIndex[1], PrevAsiaIBLow, AsiaBoxIBOutline, 1, SolidDotted, extend.right,bgcolor=AsiaBoxIBBGColor)


// Draw current box if currently in range
box AsiaIBBox = na
if AsiaIBinRange and barstate.islast and AsiaIBOnOff and isToday
    AsiaIBBox := box.new(AsiaIBStartIndex, AsiaIBHigh, bar_index, AsiaIBLow, AsiaBoxIBOutline, 1, SolidDotted, extend.none,bgcolor=AsiaBoxIBBGColor)
    box.delete(AsiaIBBox[1])
```

Comment: When we click on the ExtendIBTodayBox or ExtendIBYesterdayBox, it also plots additional 2 boxes starting from previous month. How to restrict these boxes from the previous months.